# SBT unresolved dependecie with Akka

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, akka, akka-cluster

I'm quite new to Scala, Akka and SBT, so this issue is giving me some headache! I'm working with the book **Akka in Action**, where the author provides examples on Github:
https://github.com/RayRoestenburg/akka-in-action
On a clean clone of the repository, i was trying to have a look at the example in **chapter-cluster**.

As described in the book, the first thing to do is to start a seed node on the local machine with:

```
sbt -DHOST=127.0.0.1 -DPORT=2551
```

I was trying to install another Scala version, run it with root privileges, but without success. In my understanding SBT should take care of all the versioning stuff and download the specified packages.

Error messages goes like that:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/sfink/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sfink/IdeaProjects/akka-in-action/chapter-cluster/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/sfink/IdeaProjects/akka-in-action/chapter-cluster/project/}chapter-cluster-build...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalactic#scalactic_2.10;2.2.1 compile
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalactic#scalactic_2.10;2.2.1 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalactic#scalactic_2.10;2.2.1 compile
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalactic#scalactic_2.10;2.2.1 compile
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1159)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1182)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1180)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1184)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1179)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1187)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1152)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1130)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalactic#scalactic_2.10;2.2.1 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4: configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.scalactic#scalactic_2.10;2.2.1 compile
```

**Update 1:**
This is the content of the build.sbt file:

```
name := "words-cluster"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

organization := "com.manning"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaVersion = "2.4.14"
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-actor"                        % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-slf4j"                        % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-remote"                       % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-cluster"                      % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-multi-node-testkit"           % akkaVersion   % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-testkit"                      % akkaVersion   % "test",
    "org.scalatest"           %% "scalatest"                         % "3.0.0"       % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-slf4j"                        % akkaVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback"          %  "logback-classic"                   % "1.0.10"
  )
}

// Assembly settings
mainClass in Global := Some("aia.cluster.words.Main")

assemblyJarName in assembly := "words-node.jar"
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you give us your build.sbt file?

Comment: I did an update in the original post!

Comment: "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "3.0.0" try this dependency rather than scalatest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the sbt version i was using was the wrong one! After upgrading to sbt-0.13.15 compilation was running properly.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your build.sbt:

```
name := "words-cluster"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

organization := "com.manning"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaVersion = "2.4.14"
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-actor"                        % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-slf4j"                        % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-remote"                       % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-cluster"                      % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-multi-node-testkit"           % akkaVersion   % "test",
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-testkit"                      % akkaVersion   % "test",
    "org.scalatest"           %% "scalatest"                         % "3.0.1"       % "test" exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml_2.11"),
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-slf4j"                        % akkaVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback"          %  "logback-classic"                   % "1.1.7"
  )
}

// Assembly settings
mainClass in Global := Some("aia.cluster.words.Main")

assemblyJarName in assembly := "words-node.jar"
```

I updated the scala, logging and scalatest versions

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error message after changing to "1.1.7"!

Comment: Hi I edited my answer, please try the following build.sbt

Comment: Nope, i'm sorry, but the error still exists in the same manner.